# Do I need SSH support for nodejs

Tags: ssh, hosting, shared-hosting

Hostinger offers this really cheap plan that is 1 dollar per month but it doesn't have SSH support. Do I need SSH support to host NodeJS? The plan provides shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, you need to upload the files in any way and to start the webserver/node.
But I would not like to do something like uploading my files or use npm with a webinterface.
I can highly recommend https://uberspace.de/de/
It's a shared hosting pay what you want but you have SSH access.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is supported only on VPS plans with Hostinger, you can purchase one instead of your shared hosting plan. Won't be that cheap of course and don't know if their discount code SUMMER19 still works, but you can try. VPS will require more work but if you are familiar with developing it should fit you.